# jQuery click event on image only fires once

Tags: jquery, image, click, live

I created a view of thumbnails.  When the user clicks, I want the real image to pop-up in a dialog.  That works the first time, but once the jQuery 'click' fires on an thumbnail it never fires again unless I reload the entire page.  I've tried rebinding the click events on the dialog close that that does not help.  Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
        $(".selector").tabs( {selected: 0} );
        $("img.gallery").live('click',
                function()
                {
                    var src= $(this).attr('src');
                    var popurl = src.replace("thumbs/", "");
                    PopUpImage(popurl,$(this));
                });
        // Preload animation for browser cache
        var ajaximg = new Image();
        ajaximg.src = 'images/ajax-loader.gif';
    });

    function LoadProgramsAccordion()
    {
        $(function() {
            $("#programsaccordion").accordion({
                            autoHeight: false,
                navigation: true,
                            collapsible: true
            });
        });

        $(function() {
            $("#programsaccordioninner").accordion({
                            autoHeight: false,
                navigation: true,
                            collapsible: true
            });
        });

        $(function() {
            $("#policiesaccordioninner").accordion({
                            autoHeight: false,
                navigation: true,
                            collapsible: true
            });
        });

        $(function() {
            $("#registrationaccordioninner").accordion({
                            autoHeight: false,
                navigation: true,
                            collapsible: true
            });
        });

        $('.accordion .head').click(function() {
                        $(this).next().toggle();
                        return false;
                }).next().hide();
    }

    function LoadGalleryView()
    {
        $('img.gallery').each(function(){
            $(this).hover(function(){
                $(this).attr('style', 'height: 100%; width: 100%;');
            }, function(){
                $(this).removeAttr('style');
            });
        });
    }

    function CheckImage(img,html,source)
    {
        if ( img.complete )
        {
            $('#galleryProgress').html('');
            var imgwidth = img.width+35;
            var imgheight = img.height+65;
            $('<div id="viewImage" title="View"></div>').html(html).dialog(
                    {
                        bgiframe: true,
                        autoOpen: true,
                        modal: true,
                        width: imgwidth,
                        height: imgheight,
                        position: 'center',
                        closeOnEscape: true
                    });
        }
        else
        {
            $('#galleryProgress').html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" /><br /><br />');
            setTimeout(function(){CheckImage(img,html);},50);
        }
    }

    function PopUpImage(url,source)
    {
        var html = '<img src="'+url+'" />';
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = url;
        if ( ! img.complete )
        {
            setTimeout(function(){CheckImage(img,html,source);},10);
        }
    }
```

PopUpImage() only executes the first time an image is clicked and I cannot figure out how to rebind.

Comment: have you constructed a simple html page that focuses on just this functionality/issue to rule out any other possibilities? If so i'd suggest posting it. If not that might help, it looks likes there might by an issue with part of the page you haven't shown us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, first off, refactor LoadProgramsAccordion.

```
  function LoadProgramsAccordion()
    {
        $(function() {
            $("#programsaccordion, #programsaccordioninner, #policiesaccordioninner, #registrationaccordioninner").accordion({
                            autoHeight: false,
                navigation: true,
                            collapsible: true
            });
        });

         $('.accordion .head').click(function() {
                        $(this).next().toggle();
                        return false;
                }).next().hide();
    }
```

Second, `$(function(){ ...` works the same as `$(document).ready(){ function(){...,`   keep that in mind.

`$(document).ready()` only fires one time - right after the page loads.  So if you are calling `LoadProgramsAccordion` multiple times, the inner stuff is only being executed one time.

Next, beware of `$(this)`, it can change unexpectedly. So this code

```
           function()
            {
                var src= $(this).attr('src');
                var popurl = src.replace("thumbs/", "");
                PopUpImage(popurl,$(this));
            });
```

should be changed to look like this:

```
           function()
            {
                var that = $(this);
                var src= that.attr('src');
                var popurl = src.replace("thumbs/", "");
                PopUpImage(popurl,that);
            });
```

Next, I would need to see *PopUpImage*.  You just have a lot going on to figure out where the issue is.

Comment: btw Steve, if you have too much trouble, just stop by and I can take a look at it.

Comment: $(document).ready() only fires one time - right after the page loads.  < Helped me a lot, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Chris, thanks for the heads up on $(this), I've changed my programming because of it.  For the rest, I've switched to Lightbox per your suggestion.